# Memory leak when using pika/rabbitmq while piping from an external process on Linux

Tags: python, linux, memory-leaks, rabbitmq, pika

So I've been wrestling with a problem that I can't explain for the last two days.

My goal is to use tshark (command-line Wireshark) to listen to traffic and translate packets to XML format, and relay these XML packets over rabbitmq to another worker.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import pika

def main():
    tshark_process = Popen(['/usr/bin/tshark', '-i', 'eth0', '-T', 'pdml'],
                           stdout=PIPE ,
                           shell=False)
    message= []
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters("localhost"))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue="packets", durable=True)
    for line in tshark_process.stdout:
        if "<packet>" in line:
            message = []
        if "</packet>" in line:
            message.append(line)
            full_message = "".join(message)
            channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                  routing_key="packets",
                  body=full_message,
                  properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                     delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
                  ))
            message = []
        else:
            message.append(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The worker can actually see the packets and it looks great. but when I run the command "top" I can see that the tshark process memory usage is increase all the time (about 200k a second). And after a while the python program crashes with a MemoryError since the memory gets full.

So this sounds like a tshark problem, right?

Well, when running tshark alone- the memory usage gets stable on a very low number after only 1-2 seconds, and will never rise after that.

Same thing if I comment the "channel.basic_publish" line, this problem goes away!

I'm really baffled by this issue, especially when the memory leak is coming from a third party process that shouldn't be affected in such a way.

I really hope that someone will be able to shed some light on the issue for me or even point me to a direction.

Thanks,
Dave.